# Django Getting PK from Createview

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am creating a blog post with a specific primary key (pk). My other function requires to have the pk as an input (please check the views.py). I am trying to get the post id by getting it as an object id, although it indicated that object has no attribute 'id'.

Any ideas how to get pk as a variable?

Thanks,
Ted

```
#The template
{% extends "Blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content%}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method = "POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"> Blog Post </legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock content%}
```

```
#urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostListView, PostDetailView, PostCreateView, PostUpdateView, PostDeleteView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
]
```

```
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from .latex import tex
from django.http import FileResponse, Http404
from django.urls import reverse

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'titles' ,'title', 'content', 'billing']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user # Use this to get the information from the form.

        pk = self.object.id

        self.external(pk)

        return super().form_valid(form),
```

```
#Error which I am getting
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the object through the instance wrapped in the form. But as long as the object is *not* saved, it has *no* primary key.

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'titles' ,'title', 'content', 'billing']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        pk = form.instance.pk
        self.external(pk)
        return response
```

Comment: Hi Willem, i am getting the following error: ```AttributeError at /post/new

'PostCreateView' object has no attribute 'instance'```

Comment: But your `form` is not a `PostCreateView`, that should be a model for. Are you sure you did not use `self.instance`?

Comment: You were right, I was using ```self.instance.pk``` instead of ```pk = form.instance.pk```. Although I am still not getting what I was expecting. The output of  ```pk = form.instance.pk``` is ```None```

Comment: @TadasK: but *before* or *after* you perform a `super().form_valid(form)`. As I wrote in the answer, as long as the form is not saved (and that happens in `super().form_valid(form)`, the object *has no* primary key.